# jspdf autotable linebreak not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

```
$scope.exportToPdf=function(){

        $('#tableToExport').tableExport({type:'pdf',
            jspdf: {orientation: 'l',
                format: 'bestfit',
                margins: {left:10, right:10, top:20, bottom:20},
                autotable: {styles: {overflow: 'linebreak',
                    rowHeight: 60,columnWidth: 'wrap',textColor: 50},
                    columnStyles: {
                          4: {columnWidth: 'auto'}
                        },
                    tableWidth: 'auto',
                    fontSize: 5,
                }}
        })
    }
```

I want table to be generated as shown in this link:http://tinypic.com/r/jq0s5x/9

But in my pdf last column i.e check out-by is not visible fully when i use columnWidth:'auto' for 4th column. It is because of columnWidth:'wrap' that i have used on synid and description column(4Th column)(earlier this column's text was partially visible which was fixed by this)

This is my pdf snapshot:http://tinypic.com/r/2ur1eoh/9